# NSDictionary to NSMutableArray in objective c

Tags: objective-c

How to parse the following format?

I parsed the XML and get it into NSDictionary. But not able to convert it into NSMutableArray.

Total count of NSDictionary is showing only 1 with this format.

```
{
    rsp = {
        photos = {
            page = 1;
            pages = 3709;
            perpage = 100;
            photo = (
                    {
                    farm = 4;
                    id = 12813766723;
                    isfamily = 0;
                    isfriend = 0;
                    ispublic = 1;
                    owner = "61930219@N02";
                    secret = f2efb7b4ac;
                    server = 3672;
                    text = "";
                    title = "House of Vans 02.26.14";
                },
                {
                farm = 8;
                id = 12802578725;
                isfamily = 0;
                isfriend = 0;
                ispublic = 1;
                owner = "91434132@N08";
                secret = faecb409a2;
                server = 7374;
                text = "";
                title = DSC03312;
            }
            );
            text = "";
            total = 370847;
        };
        stat = ok;
        text = "";
    };
}
```

Comment: Did you try writing code for this? How far did you get?

Comment: What key values?  There's only one key in the outer dictionary.  And have you bothered to look at the documentation for NSArray??

Comment: What do you need in the mutable array again? You need to be more clear.

Comment: I just wanted to show the "title", "farm", "id" etc into tableview.

Answer (score 1):

You can make arrays of particular values.

Something like this

```
NSDictionary *dict;
NSArray *array = [dict allKeys];
array = [dict allKeysForObject:@"pass the object here you want to retrieve the arrays for"];
array = [dict allValues];
```

You can use the above code according to your functional requirements.

But what you have is an array of objects so you can apply a foreach and get all the values populated in a NSmutableArray

I can give you an example suppose you want to retrieve an array of owner, so what you can do is:

```
NSDictionary *dict;//Suppose this dictionary contain all the values

NSMutableArray *arrayObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary* dictionaryObjectWithCurrentVal in dict) {
     [arrayObject  addObject:[dictionaryObjectWithCurrentVal valueForKey:@"owner"]];
}
//you'll get an array containing all the owners
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the two "photo" objects:

1. Get the "rsp" object (i.e. a `NSDictionary`) from your `NSDictionary`
2. Get the "photos" object (another `NSDictionary`) from 1.
3. Get the "photo" object (a `NSArray`) from 2.

Now, you have an array of dictionaries holding the two "photo" objects.